# contar el resultado de una lista en python

Tags: python, aws, lambda

Tengo esta función en lambda que devuelve como resultado dos objetos de s3, pero necesito que el resultado se el numero 2, es decir, de la cantidad de objetos. como puedo hacer esto?

```
import json
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = s3.Bucket('replace-object')
    for my_bucket_object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prueba/prueba2/'):
        key = my_bucket_object.key
        #print(key)
        lista= [key]
        print(lista)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Aclaro que desconozco si existe una forma más eficiente y directa proporcionada por el propio SDK (al menos por lo que he visto en la documentación, no). Dicho esto, la solución general para contar los items de un iterador en Python pasa por iterar sobre él si o si. Puedes simplemente ir incrementando el valor de una variable en cada iteración o mejor usar`enumerate`:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = s3.Bucket('replace-object')
    for count, my_bucket_object in enumerate(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prueba/prueba2/')):
        print(my_bucket_object.key)
    return count + 1
```

Si realmente no vas a usar para nada los items, usa `sum`:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = s3.Bucket('replace-object')
    count = sum(1 for _ in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prueba/prueba2/'))
    return count
```